# JTXPartitionDriverImplGen.java:a.netpreferIPV4Stack=true error while compiling Java transformation in Informatica 10.2 Powercenter client

Tags: java, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am developing a mapping in Informatica Powercenter 10.2 to process data using Java transformation. I was able to resolve the code issues, however I am still getting the error

`JTXPartitionDriverImplGen.java:a.netpreferIPV4Stack=true`

while compiling the Java transformation. Please help me to understand this error and how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this first time ? Or you used JT before? Reason i am asking is - I am trying to understand this is system setup related issue or an issue solely related to this JT.

Comment: In general I recommend avoiding Java Transformation at all. Question is: what is it you're trying to achieve? Can it be done without JT?